# Remove all arbitary spaces before a line in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I'v written a plugin where it comes to parsing a XML tag. The content inside the tag is indented and when i copy the parsed string into the file it's gettting like:

```
    Example line
        This is part of the parsed line
        Thats goes one
    End of line
```

What I want is to remove all spaces in front of these lines, the final text should be

```
Example line
This is part of the parsed line
Thats goes one
End of line
```

I've tried to use `=` but it doesn't work the way I want. How can I do that with minimal key strokes ?

Comment: `=` does what you want for me when the filetype is undefined, xml or html.

Comment: That' doesn't work exactly in plugin mdoe. I don't know why. By the way, I've the solution. Just visually select all lines, and then use `:%le` , that's work perfect

Comment: If you are using the % in `:%le` then you actually don't need to visually select all lines first. :)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

To format a line to the left I use `:left`. Use this format an entire file:

```
:%le
```

Comment: I have searched Google for months with this annoying one. Got so sick of `:5<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<` I can not believe I forgot about `:left` I feel so silly now. Thank you!

Comment: for anyone wanting to do this on multiple lines, just select the lines in visual mode (`:V`) and then use `:left`

Comment: not sure if this is vim only and not vi, but neither :left or :%le worked for me.

Comment: @rtaft, According to `:h :left`, the `:left` command is not in vi.

Comment: To un-indent a paragraph, `vap` `:le`

Comment: @Harry It's easier just to do `[N]:le`.

Answer (score 13):

A simple search/replace `s/^\s*//` should do the trick, but it's probably not the minimal version.

Answer (score 9):

Personally I would visually select the lines with `V`, then use `99<` to push the text as far left as it could go.

Answer (score 6):

Just type `d` followed by `w` followed by `j` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: and if your file is 1,000 lines long? :)

Comment: Then you need a different solution or a loop. ;-) But for small files it can be faster to type those keys 20 times than a long research.

Comment: Great solution if you only have a few lines to deal with and don't want to reformat the entire file!

Comment: "and if your file is 1000 lines long?"


    `qqdw0jq999@q`


    `qq    # start macro q`
    `dw    # delete word, as above`
    `0     # return to beginning of line`
    `j     # down one line`
    `q    # stop recording macro q`
    `999@q # repeat 999 times`

same solution, with it's loop

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
:%s/^ *//
```

Or are you looking for a vim-script solution?

Comment: That will remove all of the spaces.  I think you mean `:%s/^ \+//` (`\+` will be marginally quicker than `*` as it won't replace zero spaces with nothing).

Comment: Actually, no, it will only remove the first group of spaces. But it's still wrong of course. I'll fix it.

Comment: Prefer `\s` that will match tab characters as well.

Comment: The question states explicitly "all spaces"

Answer (score 2):

To remove initial spaces and tabs at specified line numbers (E.g. from lines 5 to 10),

```
:5,10s/^\s*//
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to achieve this is using the the normal command `:h :normal-range`

```
:%norm d^
```

This goes to column 0 in each line (**%**) and deletes (**d**) to the first non-white character(**^**).

This is slightly more to type as the accepted answer, but allows for easy extension if you have a more complex scenario in mind, such as additional un-commenting or so:

```
:%norm d^I#
```

Resulting in:

```
#Example line
#This is part of the parsed line
#Thats goes one
#End of line
```

Answer (score 0):

The search/replace suggested by Lukáš Lalinský or the `%le` approach in the wikia page is probably the way I'd do it, but as another alternative you could also do:

```
:%< 99
```

As a quick way to shift the whole file (`%`) 99 times to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all consecutive spaces: `:%s/  */ /g`

It was useful to me to go from:

```
$screen-xs-min:              480px;
$screen-sm-min:              768px;
$screen-md-min:                992px;
$screen-lg-min:                  1200px;
```

To:

```
$screen-xs-min: 480px;       
$screen-sm-min: 768px;       
$screen-md-min: 992px;           
$screen-lg-min: 1200px;
```

Comment: Even shorter: `:%s/ +/ /g`

Comment: @SeantheBean It will have to `:%s/ \+/ /g`