# Vim align text to left side

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Given something like:

```
dadscasd
  cas
    casdc
```

How, in vim, can I alight all lines to left side?

```
dadscasd
cas
casdc
```

I installed [vim tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular). I know how to align a pattern but have no idea about how to align everything to left. Also not sure vim tabular is the right tool for the job.

Comment: but you know you can move lines with `<<` or `<2j` and things like that?

Comment: Actually no, can you say more about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Remove all arbitary spaces before a line in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4625598/438329)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To do this easily without any plugins**
In normal mode, press:

```
ggVG<<
```

and then press `.` as many times as you need to.

An explanation of the commands

- `gg`: jump to the top of the file
- `V` : start a visual selection that grabs entire lines at a time
- `G` : go to the end of the file (in this case, selecting everything from start to end)
- `<<`: move selected text left by one indentation
- `.` : repeat last command (in this case, the one that says we should indent everything in the file one left)

If you don't want to do all the lines, you only need to select the lines you want to move, using `v` or `V`. Then press `<<` or `>>` to start indenting. Once again, `.` will repeat the last command issued to make your life easier.

To learn more, open vim and without typing anything else, type `:h <<` and hit enter.

**A faster way, without visual confirmation, is to type**

```
:%left
```

where `%` in this case means the whole range of the current buffer, as it is an alias for `1, $`.
see `:h left` and `:h range`

Comment: `:%left` is way shorter than your solution. Visual selection is useless here anyway, `gg<G` does the same.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo our friend asking the question here does not know about `<<`, so I figured it would be safer to assume he is new to vim and guide him with some visual selections, which I find let the user feel a bit more secure in what they are manipulating because of visual feedback.

Comment: That's a valid reason for visual selection then. Thanks for clearing it up. However, would be nice to include both forms next time ;)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I edited my post to include your solution inside it.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Sorry if I confused you. It is of course alright to not include `:%left` as a solution. It is okay to post an answer if you don't know anything about vim (I am still missing a lot of the power of vim, and I most certainly will never use all of it). But what I meant is, if you include the visual mode only to make it easier to understand, it would be nice to include the solution without visual mode too. Hope it is all clear now and I didn't demotivate you. I am just trying to learn you new things. And I still get corrected a lot here from the real pros ;-)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo not a problem, it's a good and valid solution, which is why I put it in. It improves the answer.

Answer (score 8):

First of all have a look at  `:h shift-left-right` that explains a lot.

For your usecase `:h left` would be better. I would do it like that:

Visual select all 3 lines (`c-v` and then type `:left`)
or if you want the whole file left-aligned: `:%left`

For even more options you could look at `:h formatting`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you want to practice your regex usage

```
:%s/\v^[ ]+//c
```

Which means:

```
:%  an ed command, apply to entire file 
s    I think this means 'sed' = 'stream edit' = find and replace
/    Use this as the separator for the next 3 fields (the find, the replace, and the sed commands)
\v  Means use "very magic mode" of vim ie characters not 0-9A-Za-z have special meanings and need escaping
^    The start of the line
[ ]   A space character (or whatever characters are present between the [ ]. I believe you could use \s instead to represent any space including tabs
+    Means find 1 or more, but select as many as possible (greedy)
//    ie replace with the 'nothing' between the separators here
c     Means confirm each replacement. You could omit this to do it automatically.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple regex is:

`:%s/^\s\+//`

Is useful because its simplicity, `^` match first character of a line, `\s` for white spaces, `\+` multiplier.