# Vim: unindent multiple lines to the beginning

Tags: vim

Suppose I have something like this:

```
line 1 with text
    line 2 with text
         line 3 with text
              line 4 with text
```

I want to unindent all of these lines to the beginning, like this:

```
line 1 with text
line 2 with text
line 3 with text
line 4 with text
```

`Shift + V <` gives me ONE level of un-indentation. How can I get them all to the beginning? Sorry, I'm having trouble phrasing this...

Comment: Shift_V+======== doesn't do it, I don't think? I want to do all lines at once.

Comment: Related post: [Remove all arbitary spaces before a line in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4625598/438329)

Comment: I've found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628391/2571881) with a good solution: :%le

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different ways you could do this:

1. Visually select all of the lines, press `<`, and then press `.` as many times as you need until there is no indent left. Or if there are a specific number of lines you would like this on, you could do something like

   - `5<<` (unindent 5 lines)
   - `<j` (unindent this line and the next)
   - `<ip` (unindent inside this paragraph)

   followed by as many `.` as you need.
2. Select all of the lines, and then type either `:norm d^` or `:s/^\s*`

Also, `Shift-V + V + <` is basically the same as `<<`.

Comment: I believe you ;)