# Vim shortcut for unindenting till the start of the line

Tags: vim, vi

So I'm aware that you can unindent a line with the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (or <kbd><</kbd>) and that you can repeatedly apply it by pressing a number before the shortcut -- for example, <kbd>5</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> will unindent 5 times.

Is there a way to repeatedly apply unindent until it reaches the start of the line?

Comment: Related post: [Remove all arbitary spaces before a line in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4625598/438329)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `^d0`: move to the start of the indented line, then delete to the start of the entire line.

Sometimes it’s just easier to `<<` then mash `.` to repeat, though.

Answer (score 2):

#### Moving to the `:left`

You can move lines to the left with `:left` . This will remove all indention.

```
:left
```

See `:h :left` for more information.

#### Putting with indentation

I often find myself wanting to move/cut a block of code and put/paste with the current line's indention level. This can be done with `]p` & `[p`.

Example:

```
def foo():
    pass
if x == 'bar'
    print "hello world"
```

Assuming you are on the `if` line you can do the following:

```
dj]p
```

This will put/paste the block inline with `pass` yielding:

```
def foo():
    pass
    if x == 'bar'
        print "hello world"
```

Note: `]p` & `[p` need the register to be linewise for this to work correctly or use [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired)

For more help see:`:h ]p` & `:h linewise`